# Couldn't precompile jsps using ANT script-Weblogic server

Tags: java, ant, weblogic

I'm working on an ANT script now for a web application(And I have very minimal knowledge in ant script and weblogic server administration).

When I execute the ant script , everything work fine except the script fail to precompile the jsps. PFB the ant script for jsp precompile

```
  <!-- run jsp compile -->
  <target name="jspc" unless="warBuild.notRequired" depends="compileAll">
    <java classname="weblogic.jspc" fork="yes" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="-compiler ${WL_COMPILER} -nowarn -compileAll -webapp ${build} -depend -d ${classes}"/>
      <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${app.classpath};${classes}"/>
      </classpath>
    </java>
  </target>
```

And PFB the error log

> jspc:
> [java] java.lang.NullPointerException
> [java]     at weblogic.jsp.internal.java.JavaCompilationContext$JavacJavaCompilationContext.init(JavaCompilationContext.java:67)
> [java]     at weblogic.jsp.internal.CPL.createJavaCompilationContext(CPL.java:584)
> [java]     at weblogic.jsp.internal.CPL.setClassLoader(CPL.java:555)
> [java]     at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspCLLManager.initCompilerOptions(JspCLLManager.java:396)
> [java]     at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspCLLManager.initialize(JspCLLManager.java:235)
> [java]     at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspCLLManager.(JspCLLManager.java:228)
> [java]     at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspCLLManager.(JspCLLManager.java:221)
> [java]     at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspCLLManager.compileJsps(JspCLLManager.java:126)
> [java]     at weblogic.servlet.jsp.jspc20.runBodyInternal(jspc20.java:456)
> [java]     at weblogic.servlet.jsp.jspc20.runBody(jspc20.java:265)
> [java]     at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158)
> [java]     at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115)
> [java]     at weblogic.jspc.main(jspc.java:22)
> [java] Unexpected exception while compiling jsps :java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Weblogic version - 10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the JRE version of Weblogic and JRE version used in the workspace(Eclipse) was different. As a result the compilation of jsps were failed. I have changed the recommended JRE version, i.e. jre1.6 (for Weblogic 10.3.5) and it worked fine.